# He is one of the men who do/does the work

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Let us say, I have been given two sentences in an MCQ test and I need to pick up the correct one.

- He is one of the men who ***do*** the work.
- He is one of the men who ***does*** the work.

Somehow, I lean towards the second one ("It is I who am to blame", the one sentence memorized to take care of cases like this), but I have found some grammar books supporting the first one.

Comment: I think you memorized a right sentence for the wrong reason. *It is I ...* is a cleft sentence, not to be confused with *I am one of those men who ...*. I think your example is probably debatable. Compare: *"He is [the only one of the men] who does the work."* and *"He is one of [the men who do the work]."* See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134539/singular-verb-following-one-of

Answer (score 3):

The second one is the better choice, because *does* agrees with *one*. Here, *men* is the target of the preposition *of*. The phrase *of the men* serves to qualify *one*; it is not the subject of the clause.

If you remove *of the men*, you can see that *does* is correct (though *one* then needs a specifier; I add *the* to fulfil this requirement):

> He is the one who *does* the work.

The emphasis here is on a single man. Though he is not the only one *who does the work*, he is the subject of discussion. The sentence isn't talking about a group of men; it's talking about one man who also happens to be part of a group. Thus, *do* should be conjugated to agree with *one*.

Comment: I read your answer and I am not sure which one you prefer as is. It sounds like you seem to prefer *does* in both *He is one of the men who does the work,* and *He is the one who does the work.*

Comment: Regarding the sentences presented in the question, I definitely prefer the second version, *he is one of the men who does the work*. You are right that I use *does* in both cases, because the both employ the singular subject *one*.

Comment: I beg to differ (on the OP's case). However, as I stated in my comment posted directly to the OP, I think it's debatable, and this is probably an edge case. I think I'd prefer *He is one of the men who do the work*, but *He is the one of the men who does the work,* and yet the context could change my mind. (By the way, there are several ambiguous cases where I've seen both usages, e.g. *"I am one of the people who ...",* *"I am one of those people who ..."*, *"I am one of the men who ..."*, *"I am one of those men who ..."* To me, some of them are clear (which one to use), but some aren't.

Comment: Hmm... I think I got an idea about this. I think the difference in our preferences is based on different contexts we assume for the example sentence. I think you could read *He is one of the men who ...* as if it is in a context where *the men* has already been clearly defined, so *He is the one who does it* fits better. However, if we assume that this is an opening sentence, *the men* is undefined, thus it should be read as *the men who do the work*, and he is just one of them. Context is very important, I think.

Comment: An excellent point, as context is extremely important in English. My answer alludes to this (*he is one* is the independent clause and emphasizes the singular man rather than the group doing the work) but further elaboration might call for a different reading than my initial reaction.

Answer (score 0):

The object of a preposition can NEVER be the subject of the sentence.  One is the subject; men is the object of the preposition of.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it sounds wrong, but option 1 is the correct answer. The antecedent of "who," the subject of the relative clause, is "men." To achieve subject-verb agreement, the situation calls for the plural verb "do" to agree with "men" (as in "men do," not "men does").